# Adding command line arguments to AppImage

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, appimage

When opening an appImage with double click, is there some way to automatically add command line arguments?

Why: on a fresh UBUNTU MATE 22.04 installation, I'm having problems with some appImages: most of them successfully open, others open and close immediately;
I'm experiencing this in particular with

**mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage**

If launched by double click, it opens and close.
If launched from command line I get this error:

> [21690:0908/111927.721030:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

I found [here](https://forums.balena.io/t/strange-error-message-gpu-process-isnt-useable/357119/2) a working solution, which successfully opens the appImage, namely launch the appImage with the following arguments:

> ./mendeley-reference-manager-2.77.0-x86_64.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox

Then, I was wondering if I can make the double-click launch the appImage with these arguments.

Thanks,
Valerio

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) for desktop integration. When first opening an AppImage file it creates a `.desktop` file with the execution command in `~/.local/share/applications`. You can manually add the desired command line arguments there:

```
Exec=sh -c "/home/user/Applications/mendeley-reference-manager-2.80.1-x86_64.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox"
```

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/u7y47t/launch_and_integrate_appimage_with_parameter/)